# Laravel A4 print layout issue

Tags: html, css, laravel, printing

I have issue with printing in Laravel while selecting the A4 size from print options. The content of the page is not adjusting itself to the paper and it gets margin from left. But When I select the letter size everything is ok. I need the A4 landscape mode for printing.

I added some print mode styling but all of them did not work. currently It does not have any print mode styling.

Letter size
[image]

A4 Size
[image]

Answer (score 0):

add margin on direct css on the same page you are printing. like this way,

```
<style>
    @media print {
        @page {
            size: landscape
        }

        html,
        body {
            height: auto;
            font-size: 16pt;
            color: black;
        }
        .margin {
            margin-left: 10px; // ad your own
        }
    }
</style>
```